# Antonym of "recurrent"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, uniquity

What is the antonym of *recurrent*? This is like I have to few activities which I have to perform each month so these are recurrent but there are few activities which I only perform once. So what should I say this activity is recurrent and that activity is *one time*? What is the proper word in this situation?

Comment: The most direct and obvious answer for an active that occurs just one time is a *one-time activity*, or a *one-shot* one.  But isn’t that already in your question?

Comment: Question seems to be wrongly phrased. Why are you assuming that the word you are looking for would be an antonym of "recurrent"?

Comment: [One-off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recurrent)

Comment: Also, 'ad hoc'.

Answer (score 4):

[One-time](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-time), [one-off](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-off), and in some situations, [one-shot](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-shot) will all fit the bill.  Also *[singleton](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/singleton#Noun)* and *[nonce](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonce#Noun)*.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [isolated](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/isolated) or [one-off](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-off).

Answer (score 1):

- *seldom*
- *infrequent*
- *non-periodic* (not a good one but can be usable in certain situations)

I think there can be multiple words that can be used depending on how you like it.